# Conditional output plot

Tags: r, shiny

Suppose I have a conditional panel

```
fluidRow(column(12,selectInput("models", label = "Models",choices =list("choice 1"=1,"choice 2"=2))))    

tabsetPanel(tabPanel(strong("plots"),
                             plotOutput("plot 1"),
                             plotOutput("plot 2")))
```

Now, according to some select input value, I want to show `plot 1` or `plot 2`. Is there a way to to that in a shiny app ?

Comment: You may need the `conditionalPanel`  Please provide a reproducible example so that other can help you better

Comment: I prefer using `shinyjs::hide` http://deanattali.com/2015/04/23/shinyjs-r-package/

Comment: another possibility is to have a single `plotOutput`, and choose which plot to render on the server, e.g. something like `if (identical(input$selectvalue, "plot1" {plot1()} else plot2())`

Comment: @PoGibas the idea is that I don't want to launch a data processing for each plot and then hide some of them

Comment: @akrun I have just edited my post

Comment: @ChristophWolk you mean I don't set any plot in `tabsetPanel` and then run them on the server side. Knowing that in fact I have 5 plots for each choice of the `selectInput` and you mean I should wrap each of these plots with a condition ?

Comment: So this is a bit unclear: Do you have 5 plots that you always want to show, but what these plots are depends on the value of a `selectInput`, or do you have 5 plots, and you want to use a `selectInput` to choose which one to plot?

Comment: @ChristophWolk sorry I was not clear, in fact for each of the `selectInput` value, I have a set of 5 plots that I want to show. So in total, I have 10 ones, but I want to show a group of 5 plots with respect to the `selectInput` value ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First version, with selection in the render:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12,selectInput("models", label = "Models",choices =list("A-Plots"=1,"B-Plots"=2)))),    

tabsetPanel(tabPanel(strong("plots"),
                     lapply(1:5, function(i) plotOutput(paste0("plot", i))))))

server <- function(session, input, output) {

 plotsA <- lapply(1:5, function(x) function(y) (plot(1:10, main=paste("Plot A", x))))

 plotsB <- lapply(1:5, function(x) function(y) (plot(1:10, main=paste("Plot B", x))))

 for (i in 1:5) local({
   my_i <- i
   output[[paste0("plot", my_i)]] <- renderPlot({
     switch(input$models, "1"=plotsA, "2"=plotsB)[[my_i]]()})
 })}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Version 2 with `conditionalPanel`:

library(shiny)

```
ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12,selectInput(
  "models", label = "Models", choices =list("A-Plots"=1,"B-Plots"=2)))),    

tabsetPanel(tabPanel(strong("plots"),
                     conditionalPanel("input.models==1",
                       lapply(1:5, function(i) plotOutput(paste0("plot", i)))),
                     conditionalPanel("input.models==2",
                       lapply(6:10, function(i) plotOutput(paste0("plot", i)))))))

server <- function(session, input, output) {

  plotsA <- lapply(1:5, function(x) function(y) (plot(1:10, main=paste("Plot A", x))))

  plotsB <- lapply(1:5, function(x) function(y) (plot(1:10, main=paste("Plot B", x))))

  for (i in 1:5) local({
    my_i <- i
    output[[paste0("plot", my_i)]] <- renderPlot({plotsA[[my_i]]()})
  })

  for (i in 6:10) local({
    my_i <- i
    output[[paste0("plot", my_i)]] <- renderPlot({plotsB[[my_i-5]]()})
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Third option, with `uiOutput`:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12,selectInput(
  "models", label = "Models", choices =list("A-Plots"=1,"B-Plots"=2)))),    

tabsetPanel(tabPanel(strong("plots"),
                     uiOutput("plots"))))

server <- function(session, input, output) {

  plotsA <- lapply(1:5, function(x) function(y) (plot(1:10, main=paste("Plot A", x))))

  plotsB <- lapply(1:5, function(x) function(y) (plot(1:10, main=paste("Plot B", x))))

  output$plots <- renderUI(lapply(switch(input$models, "1"=1:5, "2"=6:10),
                                  function(y) plotOutput(paste0("plot", y))))

  for (i in 1:5) local({
    my_i <- i
    output[[paste0("plot", my_i)]] <- renderPlot({plotsA[[my_i]]()})
  })

  for (i in 6:10) local({
    my_i <- i
    output[[paste0("plot", my_i)]] <- renderPlot({plotsB[[my_i-5]]()})
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In all cases, the plot should only be prepared if you are actually displaying that plot.